# Is there a way to make a MAP step case-insensitive in webMethods Designer?

Tags: esb, designer, webmethods

Is there a way to map fields from one document that are in camelCase to fields in another document that are in PascalCase without creating a link between each individual field?

I'm using webMethods Designer 10.15.

An ideal MAP step would look like this:
[image]

In the example above,
DocumentA contains these fields:

- fieldA
- fieldB

and DocumentB contains these fields:

- FieldA
- FieldB

I would like to create a link between DocumentA and DocumentB and have the fields of DocumentB populated with the values of the fields in DocumentA, but the result is the fields in DocumentB are not set.

I can, of course, create a link between DocumentA.fieldA and DocumentB.FieldA, but when there are hundreds of fields in a document this becomes long and tedious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As many things in the IT field, the answer is "it is possible, but..." there is always a "catch".

If you're referring to having this "case-insentive map" using the "wire mapping", the answer would be "no" - as far as I know, up to the moment (JAN-2004).

However, you can go down the "create a custom Java service" path to accomplish this: create a service that makes such case-insentive mappings for you (take a list of (source field, destination field), find the IData entries in the source pipeline, create/update entry in the target pipeline); but this approach has some cons, one of the most notably would be the lost of the graphical mapping, which facilitates the rapid understanding of the step, and consequently, the  maintenance.

If you can restrict the usage of this service to a controlled set of services, that is an acceptable risk - but I need to add I would recommend further weighting the pros and cons of such approach.